# Compile error: '__result' was not declared in this scope

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a cpp file which I am trying to compile with sourceCpp() from RStudio. It includes Rcpp.h,  all the necessary STL stuff and "using namespace Rcpp;".

Then it has several function declarations (not exported to R), the function that should be exported to R, and finally the definitions of the declared functions.

This is what I get when I try to compile:

```
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/Users/Michelle/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/Rcpp/include"  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RW_FastSwap.cpp -o RW_FastSwap.o

RW_FastSwap.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* sourceCpp_27691_fastswap(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)':

RW_FastSwap.cpp:459:9: error: '__result' was not declared in this scope

make: *** [RW_FastSwap.o] Error 1


Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("C:/Users/Michelle/Desktop/Google Drive/FastSwap/RW_FastSwap.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

That line number is 15 lines more than the last line of the cpp file, i.e. the last line of the cpp file is 444. I've made sure that the type of the result returned from the exported function matches the return type of the function.

Any guidance on fixing this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the file saved? What happens if you delete the `.o` file and try again?

Comment: How do I delete that .o file?

Comment: What version of Rcpp? What is the actual source file generated -- can you post the output of `sourceCpp(..., verbose=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 2):

We may need to see the code, or a mocked up version.

When you use the `compileAttributes()` function to compile an Rcpp function---be it by pressing the button in RStudio, or explicitly---it creates additonal code around your code sample (essentially dealing with data conversion etc).

I think I may have seen that error when I did something silly like not including a correct return statement.

*Edit based on Ian's comment:*  This works for me (with manual line break here for SO)

```
R> cppFunction("IntegerVector fastswap(const NumericMatrix x, const int p, \
                    const IntegerVector S_init, const IntegerVector fixed_in, \
                    const IntegerMatrix order) { return S_init; }")
R> str(fastswap)
function (x, p, S_init, fixed_in, order)  
R>
```

So you may have a problem with your computer setup. But as there is little *reproducible* here nobody can say for sure.

Comment: If I comment out the body of the function and turn it into this: IntegerVector fastswap(const NumericMatrix x, const int p, 
                          const IntegerVector S_init, 
                          const IntegerVector fixed_in, 
                          const IntegerMatrix order) {
return S_init; } - I still get the same error.

Comment: The underscore is there in S_init, just not showing here on the comment for some reason.

Comment: Do you understand that I just showed that your code compiled on my computer? Hence it is not your code.

Comment: Thanks Dirk and Jens. I copied the functions one by one into a new cpp file, compiling after each copy to try and find where the error was creeping in. In the end everything compiled without a hitch, although the functions were in a slightly different order. Cant think why the order would have been a problem, but it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Dirk, would you like me to email you the working and non-working versions of the code?

Comment: Gosh, no.  StackOverflow questions are meant to contain reproducible code.